# Программа, которая загадывает число и пользователь в несколько попыток пытается его отгадать

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Написал вот такую программу. В течении 7 попыток пользователь должен отгадать число, но вот незадача попытки не считаются и не выводятся пользователю при ответе. Хотя без DOM (на alert'тах) программа адекватно работает...Буду очень признателен за помощь!

```js
 var answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    
    function playGuessNumber() {
        var tryFirst = 1;
        var tryLast = 7;
        var userAnswer = document.getElementById('userNumber').value;
        while (tryFirst <= tryLast) {
            if (userAnswer > answer) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Вы ввели большее число';
            }
            else if (userAnswer < answer) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Вы ввели меньшее число';
            }
            else if (userAnswer == answer) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ('Верно, вы угадали загаданное число, с ' + tryFirst + ' попытки');
                break;
            }
            else {
                'Чтобы угадать, нужно вводить число'
            }
            if (tryFirst > tryLast) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ('К сожалению вы не угадали. Было загаданно число ' + answer);
            }
            tryFirst++;
        }
    };
    
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', playGuessNumber);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
<input id="userNumber" /><button id="submit">Отправить</button>
```

'result' - это соответственно id параграфа в котором отображается сообщение. А 'userNumber'- поле для ввода ответа игроком.

Comment: inner html не выводится?

Comment: `else { 'Чтобы угадать, нужно вводить число' }` - очепятка?

Comment: inner html выводится, но пишет всегда что "вы угадали с 1 попытки..."

Comment: когда у вас функция запускается?

Comment: Поправьте сниппет как в вашем варианте

Comment: onclick = "playGuessNumber()"

Comment: нужно вынести переменные за её границы. вообщем внизу уже ответили)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная проблема была в цикле `while`. Дело в том, что вы его зацикливали, не давая ввести другое значение. Он там совсем не нужен.

```js
 var answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    var tryFirst = 1;
    var tryLast = 7;
    var tries = document.getElementById('tries')
function playGuessNumber() {
console.log(tryFirst)
    var userAnswer = document.getElementById('userNumber').value;
        if (userAnswer > answer) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Вы ввели большее число';
        }
        else if (userAnswer < answer) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Вы ввели меньшее число';
        }
        else if (userAnswer == answer) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = ('Верно, вы угадали загаданное число, с ' + tryFirst + ' попытки');

        }
        else {
            'Чтобы угадать, нужно вводить число'
        }
        if (tryFirst > tryLast) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = ('К сожалению вы не угадали. Было загаданно число ' + answer);
        }
        tryFirst++;
        tries.innerText = tryFirst;
  
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userNumber">
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="playGuessNumber()">play</button>
<div id="tries"></div>
```